# Extending the Proof for $\det(AB) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$ from the $3 \times 3$ to the $n \times n$ case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, proof-explanation, matrix-calculus

I want to prove that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \cdot \det(B)$ in the case where $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

This seems to  be a generalization of the case where $A, B, and A\times B = C$ are $3 \times 3$ matrices, but it doesn't seem to me that all of the same steps hold.

Specifically, if we took $C = AB$ and took each of the three columns of $C$ as vectors, we would say $\det(C) = \vec{c}_1 \times \vec{c}_2 \cdot \vec{c_3}$.

Then, since we can write any column of $C$ as $\vec{c}_i = \sum\limits_{n=1}^3b_{n, i} \vec{a}_n$, we could do the same for all three columns and write this triple product as $\det(C) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^3b_{n, 1} \vec{a}_1 \times \sum\limits_{k=1}^3b_{k, 2} \vec{a}_2 \cdot \sum\limits_{m=1}^3b_{m, 3} \vec{a}_3$.

From this point onward, I understand the proof in the $3 \times 3$ case.

However, it seems that my professor, in generalizing this to the $n \times n$ case, has followed a similar procedure, and written this determinant of $C$ as the determinant of a product of $n$ of these factors of the same form as the above expressions for a general column.

This triple product formula as a representation of the determinant, I believe, is only applicable to the $3 \times 3$ case, which is why I don't believe he is replicating that, but it also doesn't seem to me that we could simply multiple the columns of the matrix $C$ together: the dimensions wouldn't line up. This might just be an issue with me failing to understand his write-up, though I'm hoping someone is able to make sense of this and can maybe explain the logic of how we might generalize the simpler proof.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can start by using a base case for n=3, with  $3\times 3$ matrices A, B, and then hypothesize it holds for the n= k case, and then based on this hypothesis, prove it  holds for the n = k+1 case.

Comment: How is the determinant defined in this discussion?  Is it just the value you get on expansion by minors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  is  well known that the  "Determinant" is  the unique antisymmetric $n$-linear  map 
$$ Det: \overbrace{\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\times \ldots\mathbb{R}^n}^{ n-times} \to  \mathbb{R}  $$ which satisfies $Det(I_n)=1$(You can  find  this  in Linear  algebra  of  Hoffman)

Note  that  we  identify  a  matrix  with  a $n-$tuple $(V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n)$ where  each $V_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ correspond  to a  column of the  matrix.

By  anti-symmetric  I  mean $\phi $  vanish on an $n$ tuple $(V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n)$ with $V_i=V_j$  for  some $i,j$.

Now  fix  a  matrix  $A$. Then define $\phi(B)=Det(AB)/Det(A)$. Then $\phi$
is  an antisymmetric $n-$linear map with $\phi(I_n)=1$. So $\phi(B)=Det(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

If one of $\det(A)$ or $\det(B)=0$, then the matrix is not invertible, so the product is not invertible and its determinant is zero.

Otherwise, we may write our matrices as products of elementary matrices and use the fact that for elementary matrices determinants are multiplicative.

Comment: Very  interesting point. But  I think that some  thing is  missing  in your  answer. According to  your  answer one  can prove  that Det(AB)=Det(A)Det(B) provided  A, B are  elementary. So  are  you  using  an  inductive  argument  to  prove  the  general case?If  so,  please  note  that the  product  of  $k-1$  elementary  matrices  is  no  longer  an  elementary  matrix. Am  I  missing  some  thing?

Comment: Every invertible matrix could be transformed to the identity matrix by elementary row operations. Thus every invertible matrix is product of elementary matrices.

Comment: You are correct on the induction method.

Comment: So  am  I  mistaken  to think that  the  proof of the  multiplicative property with  production of  elementary  matrices, does  not work?

Comment: A Linear Algebra  book may be helpful.